# cURL gives response as {"error":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported"}

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, curl

I am posting a JSON array to a url using cURL in ZF2 php.

Adding the code with JSON array below.

```
 $data = <<< JS
 {
 "runFolder": "141015_7001367R_0388_AHANRLADXX",
 "sequencingMetricsProfile": "partner_run_level",
 "barcodeSet": "partner_barcode_set",
 "sequencingSamples": [
 {
   "sequencingSampleId": "sample1",
   "lanes": [1,2],
   "barcodeSequence": "AGCTTGA",
   "targetSets": [
       "partner_cnc"
   ],
   "sequencingSampleMetricsProfile": "partner_metrics_sample_level"
 },
 {
   "sequencingSampleId": "sample2",
   "lanes": [1,2],
   "barcodeSequence": "AGCTTGT",
   "targetSets": [
       "partner_cnc"
   ],
   "sequencingSampleMetricsProfile": "partner_metrics_sample_level"
 }
 ]
}
JS;
 $adapter = new Curl();
 $client = new Client();
 $client->setAdapter($adapter);
 $client->setUri('https://api.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/2.0/xxxx/sequencingAnalysis');
 $client->setMethod('POST');
 $adapter->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 $adapter->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 $adapter->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 $adapter->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
  ));
 $response = $client->send();
 print $response->getStatusCode();
 print $response->getBody();

 print_r($response);
```

But the response says as `{"error":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported"}`

Is there any problem in header?
Or any problem in JSON
Please help

Comment: You seem to be setting the header right but the wrong header is being sent. If I were you I would switch to plain curl, that library is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @pguardiario, You are correct. its working in plain cURL